# Data Aleatória com exceção PHP

Tags: php, data

Tenho o seguinte caso:

Tenho um horário de atendimento da 08:00 as 12:00 e 13:00 as 18:00.

```
$hora_manha_min="08:00"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$hora_manha_max="12:00"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$hora_tarde_min="13:00"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$hora_tarde_max="18:00"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
```

Porém os horários das 09:00 às 09:15 e 10:45 às 11:10 já está ocupado

```
$ocupado_1_ini="09:00"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$ocupado_1_fim="09:15"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$ocupado_2_ini="10:45"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
$ocupado_2_fim="11:10"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
```

Preciso de um horário aleatório dentro do horário de atendimento que não seja dentro dos horários ocupados e que tenho um intervalo setado em variável, exemplo:

```
$intervalo="00:15"; // Pode variar conforme consulta em Web Service (String)
// Resultados possíveis: 08:30,08:45,09:15,09:30,09:45,10:00,10:15,10:30,11:15,etc
```

Desde de Já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Ok, o que você já tentou fazer? Conseguiu gerar esse horário aleatório? Será só um ou precisa do horário de início e do final? Os horários ocupados estão armazenado em variáveis tal como mostrou na pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não tentei fazer, pois não sei nem por onde começar. Preciso apenas de um horário, exemplo: 15:00. Vou alterar a pergunta, mas preciso setar um período de agendamento, exemplo: 15 em 15 min. Sim está tudo em variável como mostrado.

Comment: Precisa ser necessariamente aleatório? Não poderia, por exemplo, buscar o primeiro período disponível?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Infelizmente preciso que seja aleatório.

Comment: Tenho esta solução (https://ideone.com/hFax0f). Funciona, mas acredito que tenha formas melhores de se fazer. Postarei como resposta em breve, mas já veja se consegue entender a ideia.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Show Isso mesmo que eu precisava! Muito Obrigado depois posta sua resposta.

Comment: No caso, ali eu considerei que os horários ocupados tem duração igual ao intervalo, mas vi que no seu exemplo, `$ocupado_2` dura mais que 15 minutos. A duração pode ser mesmo maior que o período definido pelo intervalo? Outra coisa, como você está recebendo esses dados? Manter os horários ocupados em variáveis pode inviabilizar a solução, pois não tem como previamente saber quantos horários serão. Não consegue armazenar em um array?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o Intervalo sempre vai ser unico, então resolve  meu problema. Eu coloquei diferente pq achei que fosse usar, mas pensando melhor não preciso.

Comment: Ok, isso facilita as coisas. E quanto armazenar os horários ocupados em array?

Comment: Se é de 15 em 15, o ultimo horário antes do almoço não deveria ser 11:00? já que começou as 10:45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function procurahorario($manha_min,$manha_max,$tarde_min,$tarde_max,$intervalo,$horarioocupado){
    // Define o intervalo da manhã:
    $hora_manha_min=new DateTime($manha_min);
    $hora_manha_max=new DateTime($manha_max);
    $hora_tarde_min=new DateTime($tarde_min);
    $hora_tarde_max=new DateTime($tarde_max);
    $intervalo=new DateInterval($intervalo);
    // Lista de todos os horÃ¡rios:
    $horarios=array(new DateTime('00:00'));
    // Adiciona na lista os horÃ¡rios da manhÃ£ com intervalo de 15 minutos:
    $temp = clone $hora_manha_min;
    while ($temp <= $hora_manha_max){
        array_push($horarios,$temp);
        $temp = clone $temp;
        $temp->add($intervalo);
    }
    // Adiciona na lista os horÃ¡rios da tarde com intervalo de 15 minutos:
    $temp = clone $hora_tarde_min;
    while ($temp <= $hora_tarde_max){
        array_push($horarios,$temp);
        $temp = clone $temp;
        $temp->add($intervalo);
    }

    $ocupado=explode("/",$horarioocupado);
    $total_ocupado=count($ocupado);
    for($i=0;$i<$total_ocupado;$i++){
        $ini_ocupado=explode("|",$ocupado[$i]);
        // HorÃ¡rios ocupados:
        $ocupado_ini = new DateTime($ini_ocupado[0]);
        // Remove da lista os horÃ¡rios ocupados:
        if(($key = array_search($ocupado_ini,$horarios)) !== false) {
            //echo "Removendo ", $horarios[$key]->format("H:i"), PHP_EOL;
            unset($horarios[$key]);
        }
    }
    // Devolve um horário aleatório:
    $result=$horarios[array_rand($horarios)]->format("H:i");
    return $result;
}
```